# Create new object from two other by matching values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, object, foreach, find

The point is to create new object from existing listOfStudents and homeworkResults objects that are matched by email value. The goal is to use only Javascript.

An example of new object that starts like:

```
{
name: 'John',
email: 'john@gmail.com',
results: [
        {
            topic: 'HTML Basics',
            success: true
        },
        {
            topic: 'CSS Basics',
            success: false
        }
]   
},
{
name: 'Jane',
email: 'jane@gmail.com',
results: [
        {
            topic: 'HTML Basics',
            success: true
        },
        {
            topic: 'CSS Basics',
            success: true
        }
]   
}
```

here is an example of my code. something is wrong with addHwResults funktion because it is not excludes hwResults for other student.

```js
var listOfStudents = [ 
{ name: 'John', email: 'john@gmail.com' }, 
{ name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@gmail.com' }
];

var hwResults = [ 
{ topic: 'HTML Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: true }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true } ] }, 
{ topic: 'CSS Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: false }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true } ] }
];

function Stud(name, email) {
 const hwResults = [];
 this.addHwResult = function(topic, success) {
  const result = {
   topic: topic,
   success: success
  };
  hwResults.push(result);
 }
 this.getHomeworkResult = function() {
  return hwResults;
 }
}

function Lab(studentsList){
 const stud = new Stud();

 this.printStudList = function() {
  studentsList.forEach(el => {
   console.log(stud.getHomeworkResult());
  });
 }

 this.addHwResults = function(objGet) {

  objGet.results.forEach(el => {
   const resultByEmail = studentsList.find(elem => elem.email === el.email);
    stud.addHwResult(objGet.topic, el.success);
  });

 }

}

const lab = new Lab(listOfStudents);
lab.addHwResults(hwResults[0]);
lab.addHwResults(hwResults[1]);
lab.printStudList();
```

wrong result looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyA45.png)

Comment: "*something is wrong*" - could you be a bit more specific about what does not work, please?

Comment: you find const resultByEmail and what? You don't use it. It's weird.

Comment: I edited this code so many times and in this version it is not used but should in order to filter by email results

Comment: you haven't created a Stud object per student, and the Stud object doesn't output name and email.  the structure of the objects is incomplete, as is the generation of output and data structures in between.  what are the actual requirements and what kind of design is required?  modifying only addHwResult to generate output would require monkeying around that kind of defeats the purpose of using the objects as defined

Answer (score 0):

Maintains an object map for { [email]=>Stud objects }.
Iterate on original studentList object and use [email] as key for Stud object lookup:

```js
var listOfStudents = [ 
{ name: 'John', email: 'john@gmail.com' }, 
{ name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@gmail.com' }
];

var hwResults = [ 
{ topic: 'HTML Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: true }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true } ] }, 
{ topic: 'CSS Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: false }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true } ] }
];

function Stud(name, email) {
 const hwResults = [];
 this.addHwResult = function(topic, success) {
  const result = {
   topic: topic,
   success: success
  };
  hwResults.push(result);
 }
 this.getHomeworkResult = function() {
  return hwResults;
 }
}

function Lab(studentsList){
 const studs = Object.fromEntries(studentsList.map(({name,email})=>[email,new Stud(name,email)]));

 this.printStudList = function() {
  studentsList.forEach(({name, email}) => {
   console.log({ name, email, results: studs[email].getHomeworkResult()});
  });
 }

 this.addHwResults = function(objGet) {

  objGet.results.forEach(({email,success}) => {
    studs[email].addHwResult(objGet.topic, success);
  });

 }

}

const lab = new Lab(listOfStudents);
lab.addHwResults(hwResults[0]);
lab.addHwResults(hwResults[1]);
lab.printStudList();
```

Creates student object map, iterates over all results and populates student results list.  Unwraps object map into list.

```js
var listOfStudents = [ 
{ name: 'John', email: 'john@gmail.com' }, 
{ name: 'Jane', email: 'jane@gmail.com' },
{ name: 'failure', email: 'wat@aol.com' },
{ name: 'tryhard', email: 'imcool@hotmail.com' }
];

var hwResults = [ 
{ topic: 'HTML Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: true }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true } ] }, 
{ topic: 'CSS Basics', results: [ { email: 'john@gmail.com', success: false }, { email: 'jane@gmail.com', success: true }, { email: 'imcool@hotmail.com', success: false } ] }
];

const stuMap = Object.fromEntries(
  listOfStudents.map(x=>[x.email,{...x, results: []}]) )
hwResults.forEach( ({topic,results})=>
  results.forEach( ({email,success})=>
    stuMap[email].results.push({topic,success}) ))

console.log(
Object.values(stuMap)
)
```

Comment: your solution is nice. however my task is to use `addHwResult` function. And also `const lab = new Lab(listOfStudents);
lab.addHwResults(hwResults[0]);
lab.addHwResults(hwResults[1]);
lab.printStudList();`

Comment: i've basically condensed what you need to do into 2 comprehensions.  should be relatively easy to insert or adapt the 2 map steps into your 2 object wrapped structure.  each mapping step would most likely be enclosed in each object type you've created

Comment: I think in this case it does not matter to use flatMap or map - the result the same

Comment: @Isa it should, or in the case of 'tryhard' example you will get incorrect results.  which isn't provided in the original, but it wouldn't make sense for every email to be present in every result.  otherwise why would you need to match (find) at all?

Comment: @user120242 you're right, I didn't notice 'tryhard'

Comment: @Isa I looked at it again, and you might be right actually.  OP's original problem might have the assumable assumption that all students are present in all results, and then you wouldn't need to filter at all.  Could probably have solved this in a much shorter one line comprehension.

Comment: @ANDREW-LVIV posted a working solution that only modifies Lab type.  Although I still recommend refactoring.  switching to object map lookups should have better efficiency than find.  Also, you should post a link to your original topic and mention explicitly your need to use your type structure and in what way.